# Print adjacency list by using multimap c++

Tags: c++, graph, dictionary

I constructed an adjacency list based on the following link: [Adjacency list](https://secweb.cs.odu.edu/~zeil/cs361/web/website/Lectures/graphbasics/pages/ar01s02.html)

---

```
struct Node
{
    string name;
    int id;
};

typedef std::multimap<Node,Node> Graph;
Graph g;

g.insert (Graph::value_type(node1, node3));
g.insert (Graph::value_type(node1, node4));
g.insert (Graph::value_type(node1, node5));
g.insert (Graph::value_type(node2, node6));
g.insert (Graph::value_type(node3, node6));
```

---

How can I print the multimap by following the structure of the following image ([Adjacency list](https://secweb.cs.odu.edu/~zeil/cs361/web/website/Lectures/graphbasics/pages/ar01s02.html))?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Graph::const_iterator it = g.begin();
while (it != g.end())
{
    std::pair<Graph::const_iterator, Graph::const_iterator> range
        = g.equal_range(it->first);

    std::cout << it->first << ": "; // print vertex

    for (; range.first != range.second; ++range.first)
    {
        std::cout << range.first->second << ", "; // print adjacent vertices
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;

    it = range.second;
}
```

Output:

```
1: 3, 4, 5, 
2: 6, 
3: 6, 
4: 7, 
5: 7, 8, 9, 
9: 5,
```

[**DEMO**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b5e2d3d095dcdcfa)

---

If you don't want that *redundant* `equal_range` call, you can operate with a single iterator as long as two adjacent elements are *equal* in terms of ordering:

```
Graph::key_compare cmp = g.key_comp();
Graph::const_iterator it = g.begin(), itEnd = g.end(), prev;
while (it != itEnd)
{
    std::cout << it->first << ": "; // print vertex

    do
    {
        std::cout << it->second << ", "; // print adjacent vertices
        prev = it++;
    }        
    while (it != itEnd && !cmp(prev->first, it->first));

    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

[**DEMO 2**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cd7bc7199a704612)

Comment: I missed this, +1 btw

Comment: Can't `range.second` be reused to advance `it`, i.e. `it = range.second` at the loop end?

Answer (score 2):

The following alternative solution makes use of C++11's range-based for loop. It iterates through all entries regardless the source node, and compares the current source node with the previous one. If they're different, start a new line in the output.

Compared to the solution using `equal_range`, this alternative is a little bit more cache-friendly: it only iterates over the whole graph once in the order of the nodes. `equal_range` first searches for the end of the range with the same source node, and then the loop iterates again over these elements. My alternative solution avoids this. (Of course, I did no benchmark and this is not to be meant as the ultimate fastest solution, but I just wanted to provide an alternative.)

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Graph& g)
{
    auto prev = g.begin()->first;
    os << prev << ": ";
    for (auto e : g) {
        if (e.first < prev || prev < e.first)
            os << std::endl << (prev = e.first) << ": ";
        os << e.second << ", ";
    }
    return os << std::endl;
}
```

[Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6af70acc188e216b)

If you implement `operator!=` for your `Node` type, the `if`-line can be simplified to a more readable comparison:

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Graph& g)
{
    auto prev = g.begin()->first;
    os << prev << ": ";
    for (auto e : g) {
        if (e.first != prev) // <--- now more readable
            os << std::endl << (prev = e.first) << ": ";
        os << e.second << ", ";
    }
    return os << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: consider that `Graph` may not be using `std::less<Node>` as ordering predicate, so `e.first < prev` might not always work

Comment: so just replace with `cmp(e.first, prev)` for `Graph::key_compare cmp = g.key_comp();` - there's no need to check both `e.frist < prev || prev < e.first` as the iterator is in-order (first not smaller than the next element is either greater or equal, since it cannot be greater it must be equal)

Comment: äh sorry `cmp(prev, e.first)` instead of the other way around!