# how to traverse through a adjacency list ??? for a weighted graph

Tags: c++, arrays, vector

So, this is how the list is being represented:

```
vector<vector<int>> adj[];
```

And the values are stored as

Input:

```
3 3
0 1 5 
1 2 3
0 2 1
```

I'm don't fully understand how to access those elements.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Print adjacency list by using multimap c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26274889/print-adjacency-list-by-using-multimap-c)

Comment: Please read similar questions and try to make your hands dirty before ask question:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26274889/print-adjacency-list-by-using-multimap-c

Answer (score 0):

Everything you need should be present here: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/graph-implementation-using-stl-for-competitive-programming-set-2-weighted-graph/

Answer (score 0):

```
vector< pair<int,int> > adj[100];   /* The size depends on the number of the largest vertex  */

int main(){

    int n, m;
    cin >> n >> m;    /*  n: Number of vertices, m: Number of edges   */
    for(int i = 0; i < m; i++){
        int u, v, w; 
        cin >> u >> v >> w;

        /*  If it is an undirected graph */
        adj[u].push_back({v, w});   /*  u->v    */
        adj[v].push_back({u, w});   /*  v->u    */


        /* If it is a directed graph  */
        // adj[u].push_back({v, w});   /*  u->v    */
    }

    /*   print  */
    for(int u = 0; u < n; u++){     /* If the least numbered vertex is 0  */
        cout << u << ": " << endl;
        for(auto& e : adj[u]){
            int v = e.first;      /*  u->v   */
            int w = e.second;
            cout << "    -> " << v << " (" << w << ")" << endl;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

input:

```
3 3
0 1 5
1 2 3
0 2 1
```

output:

```
0: 
    -> 1 (5)
    -> 2 (1)
1:
    -> 0 (5)
    -> 2 (3)
2:
    -> 1 (3)
    -> 0 (1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be mixing vectors and arrays.

```
vector<vector<int>> adj[];
```

The above seems to be odd. It's probably the below:

```
vector<vector<int>> adj;
```

Now for a 3x3 matrix you access the elements like so

```
adj[row][col]
```

So something like:

```
for(int row = 0; row<3; ++row)
 for(col = 0; col<3; ++col)
   cout<<adj[row][col];
   cout<<"\n";
```